# How to reset locale settings in Debian?

Tags: debian, locale, fonts

I am newbie to Debian, last night I regenerated locales using following command.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

I selected all from the prompted screen and it generated all locales. After restarting my PC I am seeing fonts as in the picture below. I need help resetting my locale settings.

[image]

Comment: I guess you can redo the same command and select what you want again, but not all options. look here for more details: [locale-settings](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33025/locale-settings-are-not-right-how-can-i-reset-them)

Comment: IIUC, your problem has nothing to do with locales but rather with fonts -- in particular with "screen smoothing" of them.  How to tweak it, depends on what desktop environment you're using.  If it's GNOME, install `gnome-tweak-tool` run it and navigate to its "Fonts" tab.

Comment: Another hint, it that in 99.9% of cases you don't need *all* locales -- it's OK to only have the `en_US` locale and the one matching your country.  It's OK to only have those with `UTF-8` encoding enabled among these two categorues.  So, most of the time you only need two locales.

Comment: @kostix Okay, thanks, is there any command so that I can reset fonts settings or repair them?

Comment: are you referring to default console-font? or all other fonts?

Comment: @MohAdnan, no command to repair (because there's nothing to repair -- you've just removed some font package or somehow managed to get some other font as system-default or somehting like that) but you can deal with your situation by picking a font that suits your visual taste and font rendering options that suit you using a font configuration tool suitable to your environment. If it's GNOME (the default DE in Debian Wheezy) then please read again what I wrote, otherwise please tell us what you have installed as your DE (KDE? XFCE? LXDE? other?).

Comment: @Digitalsite, the screenshot does not look like a terminal window to me, let alone like a VT console ;-)

Comment: @kostix Yes, I was trying to add "Urdu" fonts. I have installed gnome-tweak-tool and 'll update here.

Comment: @kostix Can you tell me which font needs to be changed from this screenshot? I have tried all but results are same as above in my post.
http://imgur.com/tXmcQjH

Comment: @MohAdnan, what software renders the fonts in your original screenshot? Is this a browser? Mozilla Firefox by any chance?

Comment: @kostix Yes, I am using Chrome and Iceweasel (Debian default) web browser. Bother rendering same fonts.

Comment: @MohAdnan, at least Firefox has its own font settings dialog. What I'm leading you to... Does the rest of the system display fonts okay and you only see non-pretty fonts in your browsers?

Comment: @kostix I am sorry, but I don't know how to reset fonts, but I have removed all my manually added fonts. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following command:

```
dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig-config
```

Font tuning method for screen (system default):
Selected  **Native** 
then for Enable subpixel rendering for screen:
selected **Automatic**
logout and login again, now fonts are normal again.

Thanks everyone here :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the contents of this file:

```
cat /etc/default/locale
```

Add a comment with your contents (would've just commented on your post but lacking the rep to do so)

Comment: Here are my locale file contents:
    #  File generated by update-locale
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: That means you are using now English US font. what font are you looking to setup?

Comment: ok, from the picture in your post, you want to change the font family to something else that was on your system!!

Comment: @Digitalsite Yes,

Answer (score -1):

I believe if you don't have the fonts, you can download them from these links:
[Ubuntu font rendering on Debian Wheezy & Sid](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=fontconfig-config)
[Download Page for fontconfig-config Debian Wheezy](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/all/fontconfig-config/download)

## Method #1

---

you can choose other packages such as Wheezy, Sid, Squeeze and so on, if you like here: [All Debain packages for fontconfig](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/fontconfig-config)

follow the steps:

```
1- Download the package.
2- open .deb file with Archive Manager
3- enter the **/etc/fonts** directory
4- open nautilus and brows to **/etc/fonts**
5- drag all the files and folders from the archive into the file browser
6- Log out and log in, and change font preferences.
```

The full procedure is on this link: [Ubuntu font rendering on Debian Wheezy & Sid](http://noz3001.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/ubuntu-font-rendering-on-debian-wheezy/)

[image: an image for clarification from the same site]

## Method #2

---

you need to recompile the package again; the original one you have on your system like this:

```
su -c 'dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig'
```

Then type:
`touch .fonts.conf`

after that, open the config file

```
nano .fonts.conf
```

Then paste in this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="hinting" >
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle" >
   <const>hintslight</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="rgba" >
   <const>rgb</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias" >
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
<match target="font">
   <edit mode="assign" name="lcdfilter">
   <const>lcddefault</const>
   </edit>
 </match>
<match target="pattern">
   <edit name="dpi" mode="assign">
   <double>96</double></edit>
</match>
</fontconfig>
```

for lolz, paste into .Xdefaults :

```
Xft.autohint: 0
Xft.antialias: 1
Xft.hinting: true
Xft.hintstyle: hintslight
Xft*dpi: 96
Xft.rgba: rgb
Xft.lcdfilter: lcddefault
```

Last, Log out and log in to see things in affect...

Comment: At this URL: http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/all/fontconfig-config/download
There is nothing but Error page.

Comment: my apology. I will edit the answer now.

Comment: What the heck? You're teaching a Debian user to *download packages in the browser* instead of just firing up a package manager, finding the package there and hitting install?! That's plain wrong on so many levels it won't fit into the comment's size limit would I have tried to explain them all. Also, font packages have nothing to do with `fontconfig` which is a tool to tweak font settings and nothing more.

Comment: now there are 2 ways how to do it, and possibly the 2nd method is easy and anyone can do it!! :)

Comment: @Digitalsite Thanks for your second method, can you mention the location of .Xdefaults file?

Comment: `.Xdefaults` is what recently called `.Xresources`. it should be in your home dir. if you don't have one, you need to create one. you can read about it [here](http://fluxbox-wiki.org/index.php?title=Xdefaults_setup)

Comment: @Digitalsite Thanks for your help, second method does affect font settings but still I am unable to read some texts. Is there anything else you want me to try?

Comment: @MohAdnan, unfortunately there is no other tweaks I know of. The second method if done correctly it should be working well. try again and change the settings.

Comment: @Digitalsite Thanks, I have reconfigured default font settings, I also added Answer in this post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: glad your issue has been solved!! Good luck.